# Realizar consulta sobre bd con condicional?

Tags: laravel

La pregunta que vengo a plantear es sencilla;

Yo realizo una consulta con `\DB`

```
$data =  \DB::table('users')->select($lo_que_sea)
->where(['vacations.aceptado' => $filtro])
->get();
```

Quiero hacer una condicion sobre ese *where* para que que si `$filtro` es nulo, no haga ese *where* algo así:

```
$data =  \DB::table('users')->select(lo que sea)
if($filtro != null){
    ->where(['vacations.aceptado' => $filtro])
    ->get();
}else{
    ->get();
}
```

Si no que simplemente haga el `->get()`, ahora mismo utilizo esta consulta de manera dinamica en dos métodos, pero si pudiera hacer el condicional no tendria que crear otro metodo o otra consulta. Para ver todas las inserciones.

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo creo que prácticamente ya lo tienes hecho:

```
$query =  \DB::table('users')->select(lo que sea);
if($filtro != null) {
   $data = $query->where(['vacations.aceptado' => $filtro])
     ->get();
} else {
   $data = $query->get();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Javier Molla no habia caido para nada en insertar las consultas en los objetos y no sabia que podia añadirle fragmentos. Asi va perfecto. Un saludo.

Comment: De nada. ¡Encantado de poder ayudar!